# How to match Android Gradient Rendering with SVG BoundingBox Units

Tags: android, svg, linear-gradients, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to replicate an SVG in Android vector drawable using the LinearGradient class. For bounding box gradient units, I am calculating the endpoints of the gradient line segment by using the following formula:

`x1 = graphic_bound.left + graphic_bound.width() * svg_boundingbox_width_percentage`

and

`y1 = graphic_bound.top + graphic_bound.height() * svg_boundingbox_height_percentage`

I am observing that the above works well for cases where `graphic_bound.width() == graphic_bound.height()`

But the rendering is different from SVG when the graphic bounds are non-square (width is not equal to height).

Any suggestions on what is the error here?

For example, the below SVGs look the same, one uses objectBoundingBox and another uses userSpaceOnUse units. My question is how to convert the objectBoundingBox values to userSpaceOnUse values to have the same visual appearance?

```
<svg width="332px" height="112px" viewBox="0 0 500 112" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>linear_gradient_direction</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="30.2395833%" y1="44.8925781%" x2="69.9661458%" y2="54.944987%" id="linearGradient-2">
            <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#000000" offset="51%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#D8D8D8" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="60" y1="30" x2="140" y2="70" id="linearGradient-3">
            <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#000000" offset="51%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#D8D8D8" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="linear_gradient_direction" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Rectangle-Box" transform="translate(5.000000, 6.000000)" stroke="#979797">
            <rect id="Rectangle" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100"></rect>
            <line x1="60" y1="30" x2="140" y2="70" id="Line" stroke-linecap="square"></line>
            <circle id="TopLeft" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="60" cy="30" r="5"></circle>
            <circle id="Center" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="100" cy="50" r="5"></circle>
            <circle id="BottomRight" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="140" cy="70" r="5"></circle>
        </g>
        <g id="Rectangle-Box" transform="translate(220.000000, 6.00000)" stroke="#979797">
            <rect id="Rectangle" fill="url(#linearGradient-3)" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100"></rect>
            <line x1="60" y1="30" x2="140" y2="70" id="Line" stroke-linecap="square"></line>
            <circle id="TopLeft" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="60" cy="30" r="5"></circle>
            <circle id="Center" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="100" cy="50" r="5"></circle>
            <circle id="BottomRight" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="140" cy="70" r="5"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: From a quick look at the GradientDrawable docs for Android - it looks like it only supports gradients drawn at 45 degree increments - unlike SVG which can support any angle. But without screenshots and code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: I am using Android's LinearGradient Shader class which accepts the gradient endpoints in pixels. I am trying to find a way to convert from bounding box percentages to user space pixel coordinates. Is there a way to do so?